# What has a greater effect on diffraction - increasing wavelength or reducing slit width?

Tags: visible-light, waves, double-slit-experiment, diffraction, wavelength

Diffraction from a slit increases when wavelength increases or slit becomes narrower. Which one would have a greater effect though - changing wavelength or decreasing slit width?

Looking for an intuitive explanation if possible.

Comment: Its all relative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the fringe spacing if the waves were projected onto a screen would be $w = \frac{\lambda D}{s}$ and hence $\delta w = \frac{D}{s}\delta\lambda - \frac{\lambda D}{s^{2}} \delta s = \frac{D}{s}(\delta \lambda - \frac{\lambda}{s} \delta s)$

You can use such a relationship to investigate how $\delta w$ changes if you vary $\delta s$ and $\delta \lambda$. For your specific question, if $\delta \lambda$ and $\delta s$ are equal in magnitude (but $\delta s$ is negative), then the change in wavelength will have greater influence if $\frac{\lambda}{s}$ is less than 1.

Note, it is impossible to predict which will have greater effect unless we know the magnitude of the change of each!